# Permission need to be removed for multiple users from file

Tags: perforce

In our organization perforce depot user permissions are managed through `group text` files. For each branch two type of files are maintained to manage the user permission under perforce version control itself.  Both `Write` and `Open` permission file sample as follows.

**ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_WRITE.txt - For Write permission:-**

```
# //DEPOT/ABCD/PROJECT/Jerd
# Permission: WRITE

dreac.leoson
ritu.bhangale
makyen
markerikson.s
bernardo.pereira 
elitezen
```

**ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_OPEN.txt - For Open permission:-**

```
# //DEPOT/ABCD/PROJECT/Jerd
# Permission: OPEN

areg.vera
bataklik
jeff.B
michael.chel
muthulakshmi.m
```

With above format we have multiple text files for each branch and now we need to remove the users permission from text file based on branch name list.

Branch name already available in our group text files. Now what is the best method remove the permission for each user? Is there any script to perform this action? since we have multiple users and branches.

Answer (score 0):

I might suggest turning these text files into groups:

```
Group: ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_WRITE
Users:
    dreac.leoson
    ritu.bhangale
    makyen
    markerikson.s
    bernardo.pereira 
    elitezen
```

```
Group: ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_OPEN
Users:
    areg.vera
    bataklik
    jeff.B
    michael.chel
    muthulakshmi.m
```

and then specifying your protections table in terms of those groups:

```
Protections:
    write group ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_WRITE * //DEPOT/ABCD/PROJECT/Jerd/...
    open group ML_PROJECT_APPLICATION_OPEN * //DEPOT/ABCD/PROJECT/Jerd/...
```

My recommendation would be to just use Perforce's interface directly rather than having your own file format and writing a script that translates it into Perforce commands, but if you do need to write that script it seems like a pretty straightforward pattern matching exercise.

Comment: Actually we are not p4 admin members to modify the protection table, Since the permissions are managed through text files, we have got permissions to modify group text files. Could you please share the straight forward pattern matching logic. (Or) if possible could you please share the code. It will be great helpful.

Comment: We need to remove the members from text file and it need to be checked-in into perforce. Because group text files are maintained in perforce version control.

Comment: The easy (and correct) solution is to set up a spec depot so that your group specs are versioned, and set up group owners so people can modify the groups without needing admin access.  As a certified Perforce consultant of more than two decades, my thousand-dollar advice (free of charge) is that the thing with the text files is daft and you shouldn't do it.  :)  If you do feel the need to do it for unfathomable reasons, though, it's going to require either learning to code at a basic level or hiring a consultant -- nobody's going to write and maintain that script for free.